# possible to refresh (not reload) a parent page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, refresh, reload

I have a page that shows images.  if a certain record doesn't have an image associated with it yet, I provide the user with a pop-up window link so that they can upload an image.  When the user submits the form on the pop-up, it refreshes, uploads the image and then automatically closes.  Before the pop-up closes, i want to refresh (not reload) the parent.  The reason I don't want to reload is because I'm using post data to dynamically populate the page content.  If I reload, all the previous data is lost.  I tried to change `window.opener.location.reload(true);` to `window.opener.location.refresh(true);` ... but apparently that's not a valid command.

Is there a way to refresh the parent page instead of simply reloading it?

Comment: "refresh" means the same thing as "reload"...

Comment: well, when i reload the page, I lose all the post data from the previous steps.  reload seems to have the same effect as going to the url bar, and pressing enter... not the same thing as pressing f5.

Comment: how are you loading the parent content?

Comment: lol, url bar and f5 are identical. edit: url bar doesn't scroll to original location or restore form fields.

Comment: I think @Brds means to show newly uploaded image

Comment: @shapeshifter - false.  If i have a page (index.php) that has a form in it whose form action goes to itself, refreshing after the form submission is NOT the same as going to the url bar and pressing enter on it.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot - correct

Comment: @Brds then the solution I gave will work. I am using it in my projects :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the newly uploaded image, then the best way is to have a function on parent page like:

```
top.refreshImage = function(url){
    $("#<ID_OF_IMAGE_TAG>").attr("src",url);
    //Or if you are not using jQuery then usual way
    document.getElementById("<ID_OF_IMAGE_TAG>").src=url;
}
```

Then from dialog, after the image is uploaded call this function:

```
top.refreshImage("<URL_OF_NEWLY_UPLOADED_IMAGE");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, and made the assumption that you have the image url you want to load inside your page

you can simply create an image tag
set its src attribute to the image url
and then put it on your page

like this

```
node = document.createElement('img');
node.setAttribute('src', imageUrl);
list.appendChild(node);
```

you can see this in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amdorra/uWpcc/)